# Why is the sorting of output of nm different between platforms?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, nm

I have an elf file on which I perform an nm on by typing in nm -n elf.elf and I get the following output on two different machines:

**Fedora**

```
80900114 t $LFB2.testmod1
80900114 t $LFE2.main
80900114 t $LSM0.testmod1
80900114 t $LSM1.testmod1
80900114 t $LX2.testmod1
80900114 t $Letext0.main
80900114 t $Ltext0.testmod1
80900114 T _testmod1

locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**Ubuntu**

```
80900114 t $Letext0.main
80900114 t $LFB2.testmod1
80900114 t $LFE2.main
80900114 t $LSM0.testmod1
80900114 t $LSM1.testmod1
80900114 t $Ltext0.testmod1
80900114 t $LX2.testmod1
80900114 T _testmod1

locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I have displayed a small portion of the output on both machines, I have checked the locale and they look identical, what would cause the output from being in a different order on these two machines?

A alphanumeric sort also gives a different order on both machines, why so?

(Note: The nm versions are different however I would not expect the behaviour of a sort to be version specific..)

Comment: According to some [man](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html) [pages](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/nm.1.asp), `nm` defaults to sorting alphabetically by name. And your samples look like they differ only in case-sensitivity. Maybe one system has `LC_COLLATE=C`?

Comment: I am running this tool through a python script without a shell on the fedora which would default to LC_COLLATE=C. It is the locale that was different. Thanks!

Comment: You should post an answer if you've found the solution :)